# How to reset a form after form submission using ajax or how to empty the input fields in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, ajax, forms

How to reset a form after submission (which is submitted using ajax)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place this code in your **AJAX response success**

```
$(':input','#YourFormId')
     .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
     .val('')
     .removeAttr('checked')
     .removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: can you explain

Comment: I dont think there is any explanation needed for this but still since you are asking it will get all input fields with the form ID you have mentioned it will empty its value `val('')`, remove attributes  `removeAttr('checked')` and `removeAttr('selected')` for checkbox and dropdowns and will ignore fields such as button by `.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')`. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset it with jquery.

Use Below code

```
$("#form_id").reset();
```

You can do this with simple javascript as well.

```
document.getElementById("form_id").reset();
```

You can call this in ajax success method. so once your ajax call will be success it will reset the form.

Comment: could you please post html code of your form ?

Comment: I have overrided the core form which is present in Magento\Review\view\frontend\templates\form.phtml.   you can refer from that

Answer (score 0):

Following code works fine for me to clear form data after submission using ajax.

Please add below the jquery code after ajax success response.

```
$('#your-form-id')[0].reset();
```

Full Sample Code

```
    $('#quote-request-form').submit(function (event) {
        $("#suc_msg").html('');
        $("#err_msg").html('');                
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("quoterequest/index/quoterequest"); ?>',
            data: formData,
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#quote-request-form')[0].reset(); //Clear form data
                if(response.success != '')
                {
                   $("#suc_msg").show();
                   $("#suc_msg").html(response.success);
                }
                else
                {
                  $("#error_msg").show();
                  $("#suc_msg").html(response.error);
                }                       
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
```